# Publishing WCF web service manually

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7

I have a working WCF web service. When I run it using F5, I get a page and when I click the links on it, my service is called, producing the correct output. I also have set up IIS7 server and pointed the web site to a directory called *c:\web\*. In it, I have a file called *Index.html* (the one with the testing links).

Besides that, I have a DLL that I understand is the service I've created. I'm not sure what to do with it, though. I'd like to (manually) setup the service to be offered via IIS. Later on I'll be using the automatic publishing facilities of VS but for now, I'd like to do the dirty work myself.

1. Where does the DLL with the service go?
2. What do I need to do in the IIS Manager to make it work?

I've googled since yesterday but I'm not getting any wiser.

Comment: How about the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question #1

1. The DLL goes into *bin* folder.
2. The *bin* folder goes into the same root directory where your *web.config* is located.
3. The *web.config* goes to the root of the web site that you create using IIS Manager.
4. See [this image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8OhVG3vxbx0/TzOFdgr6IGI/AAAAAAAAADI/j9dByR2tZYc/s1600/P8.png) for details.

Question #2

1. Make sure to create a web site with physical path to your application.
2. Make sure that your service is in an application pool.
3. Make sure that the pool targets the right .NET framework.
4. Make sure that the bindings are set up correctly.
5. Possibly, check that your firewall isn't cranky about this particular connection.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question - the web service DLL is supposed to be inside the *bin* folder of your service after you compile.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311342/Deploying-WCF-and-Silverlight-Applications-on-IIS).

In addition, a walk-through on WCF and Silverlight application can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webservices.aspx).

Comment: Another, really good tutorial, with pictures, bells and whistles can be found [right here](http://technologyriver.blogspot.se/2012/02/prerequisites-check-windows-7.html).